# Jquery: how do I reference this selector

Tags: jquery

I want to get all the **inputs**:

- that are checkboxes,
- that are checked and
- have the class name that includes "-required".

I have this, and have tried several variation, but nothing works:
**`$("input:checkbox[class*='-required']:checked");`**

**example html:**

```
<form name="myform" method="POST">
        <div id="checkFruits">FRUITS: </div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkFruit" class="chkFruit test-234-required" name="fruit" value="Apples" />Apples <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkFruit" class="chkFruit test-234-required" name="fruits" value="Oranges" />Oranges <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkFruit" class="chkFruit test-234-required" name="fruits" value="Pears" />Pears <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkFruit" class="chkFruit test-234-required" name="fruits" value="Grapes" />Grapes <br /><br />
            <input type="button" id="btnCheckFruit" value="Check Fruits" name="btnCheckFruit" />
<hr />
        <div id="checkCars">CARS: </div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkCar" class="chkCar" name="fruit" value="Lexus" />Lexus <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkCar" class="chkCar" name="fruits" value="Maxima" />Maxima <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkCar" class="chkCar" name="fruits" value="Cadillac" />Cadillac <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkCar" class="chkCar" name="fruits" value="Lincoln" />Lincoln <br /><br />
            <input type="button" id="btnCheckCar" value="Check Cars" name="btnCheckCar" />
<hr />
            <ul>
                <li>foo</li>
                <li>bar</li>
</ul>

    </form>
```

Comment: please paste you html code on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your selector seems wrong, try this one: $("input[type='checkbox'][class*='-required']:checked");

Comment: Your selector works fine for me.

Comment: @benqus: `:checkbox` is a valid selector in jQuery.

Comment: If this code is working for other people, consider the rest of your code - you may have an error or unexpected execution path that's preventing your selector from being used.

Comment: When I enter the selector into Chrome tools, it does not grab the checkboxes I am pulling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$("input:checkbox:checked[class*='-required']")` as the selector

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/89L96/1/)

Comment: OP's selector is correct. Yours will also include `radio` types.

Comment: added :checkbox filter :) Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

try this selector :

```
$("input:checked[type='checkbox'][class*='-required']");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbduzan/G64xR/1/

edit : fiddle with your example

http://jsfiddle.net/jbduzan/G64xR/2/

Comment: OP's selector is correct. Yours will also include `radio` types.

Answer (score 2):

try this selector

```
$('input.-required:checkbox:checked')
```

here's an live example

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/PQuRt/5/)

Comment: This changes the class name, and will also include `radio` types.

Comment: this will not change the class name, never the less it's true that works on radios too, so i made a little change on the selector

Comment: I mean your selector changes the class name from that which is actually being targeted. The question is targeting `-required` and you're targeting `required`.

Comment: This works, but there is a catch, in my original post, I have to have class name will include "-required"  There will be other parts to the classname such as test-234-required.  The only thing that I am sure of is the "-required" will be part of the class name.  So I need to say class*="-required"

Comment: You're welcome remember to mark as an answer if solved the problem